# Reduce amount of available stock of items in a good table based on the sales table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I have a sales table and a goods table, how can I use T-SQL to reduce the quantity of stock in goods table based on the sales table? I would like to run this once a day.

Sales table

```
customer id, itemforsaleID, quantity, price total
1            1              5          1.0  5.0
2            3              10         2.0  20.0
```

Goods table

```
ItemforsaleID  Product name quantity left
1              toy          10      
3              fruit        20
```

Comment: you make this usall with a after insert trigger, every time you sell something, once a day you can be out of stock

Comment: Thank you for your comment, do you know what the structure of the after insert trigger?

Comment: I have *assumed* SQL Server here, but if you're using using something else, such as an Azure SQL databae, Synapse, Sybase, then please correct the tag appropriately.

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Comment: This is what I have done so far. 
update goods table
INNER JOIN SALES ON GOODS.ITEMID = SALES.ITEMID
SET QUANTITY = SALES.QUANTITY - GOODS.QUANTITY

Comment: @GeorgeH99 try https://sqlserverguides.com/sql-server-trigger-after-insert/

Comment: That is a terrible article, @nbk . Honestly awful. It makes the foolish assumption of thinking an `INSERT` only ever contains **one** row. For someone that claims to be an MVP, they should not be making such an fatal flaw.

Comment: @Larnu somewhere he has to begin, the simple triggers explain the basics very well

Comment: @nbk one should never be writing a trigger with that flaw; don't learn wrong to start with.

Comment: @GeorgeH99 I think Update is a correct way to do once your sales table operation is done . you call an update statement or else you can use merge statement either (As merge statement performance is better as comapred to update) considering you have a big data

Answer (score 0):

Data Preparation

```
DECLARE @SALES AS TABLE (CustomerId INT, ItemForSaleId INT, Quantity INT, Price Decimal)
DECLARE @GOODS AS TABLE (ItemForSaleId INT, ProductName VARCHAR(100), QantityLeft INT)

INSERT INTO @SALES VALUES (1, 1, 5, 1)
INSERT INTO @SALES VALUES (2, 3, 10, 2)
INSERT INTO @GOODS VALUES (1, 'toy', 10)
INSERT INTO @GOODS VALUES (3, 'fruit', 20)
```

Data Update

```
UPDATE G
SET G.QantityLeft = G.QantityLeft - S.Quantity
FROM @GOODS AS G
INNER JOIN (SELECT ItemForSaleId, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity FROM @SALES GROUP BY ItemForSaleId) AS S
ON G.ItemForSaleId = S.ItemForSaleId
```

Results

```
SELECT * FROM @GOODS
```